# Vectorise R code to randomly select 2 columns from each row

Tags: r, vectorization

Does anyone have suggestions of how I could vectorise this code or otherwise speed it up? I'm creating a matrix, potentially very large. In each row, I want to select 2 columns at random, and flip them from 0 to 1.

I cannot select the same row and column number, i.e. the diagonal of the matrix will be zero hence the `(1:N)[-j]` in `sample()`. Because this changes with each row, I can't see a way to do this by using vectorisation, but parallelisation could be an option here?

I use `library(Matrix)` for sparse matrix functionality.

```
library(Matrix)
N <- 100
m <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)

for(j in 1:N) {
    cols <- sample((1:N)[-j], 2) #Choose 2 columns not equal to the 
    m[j, cols] <- 1
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you sample without replacement, I don't see a way to vectorize this (except implementing it in Rcpp).

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought too :( Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(Matrix)
N <- 7

desired_output <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
set.seed(1)
for(j in 1:N) {
  cols <- sample((1:N)[-j], 2) #Choose 2 columns not equal to the 
  desired_output[j, cols] <- 1
}

# 7 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                   
# [1,] . . 1 . . . 1
# [2,] . . . . 1 1 .
# [3,] . 1 . . . 1 .
# [4,] . . . . 1 . 1
# [5,] 1 . . 1 . . .
# [6,] 1 1 . . . . .
# [7,] . 1 . . 1 . .

res <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
set.seed(1)
ind <- cbind(rep(1:N, each = 2), c(sapply(1:N, function(j) sample((1:N)[-j], 2))))
res[ind] <- 1

all.equal(res, desired_output)
# [1] TRUE
```

Quick bench:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  OP = {
    desired_output <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
    set.seed(1)
    for(j in 1:N) {
      cols <- sample((1:N)[-j], 2) #Choose 2 columns not equal to the 
      desired_output[j, cols] <- 1
    }
  },
  Aurele = {
    res <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
    set.seed(1)
    ind <- cbind(rep(1:N, each = 2), c(sapply(1:N, function(j) sample((1:N)[-j], 2))))
    res[ind] <- 1
  }
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#      OP 10.240969 10.509384 11.065336 10.804949 11.044846 14.903377   100   b
#  Aurele  1.185001  1.258037  1.392021  1.363503  1.434818  4.553614   100  a
```

Comment: Hm... interesting. I will test and see how it goes.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! Much faster than my previous code. I had previously thought that the *apply functions weren't much faster than loops, however you have conclusively proven me wrong!

Comment: I think the speedup doesn't come from the apply, but rather from the one shot replacement

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I've edited my answer to make it simpler and to include the way R and RcppArmadillo make the sampling. And now it seems to be linear with `N` (as I thought it would be).

---

There are two "problems" in your code:

- `sample((1:N)[-j], 2)` is uncessary allocating memory, making your solution quadratic with `N`. The solution would be to use rejection sampling as `N` is large (so rejection will not occur often).
- you replace indices that are not "contiguous" in the matrix.

It is true that because you have sample with no replacement, it is not straightforward to make a vectorized solution for your problem. But again, it would be possible by using rejection sampling. Here I prefer an Rcpp solution:

Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix sample2(int N) {

  IntegerMatrix res(2 * N, 2);
  int j, ind1, ind2;

  for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {

    res(2 * j, 0) = res(2 * j + 1, 0) = j + 1;

    // sample first one
    do {
      ind1 = N * unif_rand();
    } while (ind1 == j);
    res(2 * j, 1) = ind1 + 1;

    // sample second one
    do {
      ind2 = N * unif_rand();
    } while (ind2 == j || ind2 == ind1);
    res(2 * j + 1, 1) = ind2 + 1;
  }

  return res;
}
```

R:

```
# table(replicate(1e5, sample2(5)))  # Verify that the sampling is OK
library(Matrix)
N <- 1000
m <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
m[sample2(N)] <- 1
```

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  OP = {
    desired_output <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
    for(j in 1:N) {
      cols <- sample((1:N)[-j], 2) #Choose 2 columns not equal to the 
      desired_output[j, cols] <- 1
    }
  },
  Aurele = {
    res <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
    ind <- cbind(rep(1:N, each = 2), c(sapply(1:N, function(j) sample((1:N)[-j], 2))))
    res[ind] <- 1
  },
  privefl = {
    m <- Matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
    m[sample2(N)] <- 1
  },
  times = 20
)
```

Results with `N = 1000`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
      OP 599.996226 605.868229 618.479868 615.653853 625.908794 679.292360    20
  Aurele  12.315795  12.633971  14.183891  13.148149  15.118948  19.649716    20
 privefl   1.401824   1.493371   1.649015   1.622826   1.704273   2.520239    20
```

Results with `N = 10,000`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq         max neval
  Aurele 812.018743 845.434915 903.387191 863.851661 967.08294 1084.738882    20
 privefl   3.657525   4.083799   4.409226   4.239576   4.49501    6.413498    20
```

Comment: Using **RcppArmadillo** like in [this example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/an-example-of-using-Rcpp-sample/) further improves performance.

Comment: Wow, that's super interesting! Makes me want to teach myself some Rcpp. Though I'm curious as to why I cannot reproduce your benchmarks on my machine, where your solution is on par with mine. Probably we have very different setups. Thanks!

Comment: @Aurèle By reproducing, you mean making it work or having the same computation times?

Comment: I can make it work. The median times are 10.3ms, 1.30ms, 1.25ms for OP, Aurele, privefl respectively. My machine is a Core i7-3740QM with Linux. But aside from performance, the Rcpp approach is very nice and you're certainly right that it has even more potential with RcppArmadillo. Upvoted your answer

Comment: Oh wait, I kept N=7 instead of N=1000 and N=5000. My mistake! Alright, I get the same results as you now (Well, almost: 620ms, 19ms, 2,50ms for N=1000 and 3400ms, 200ms and 125ms for N=5000). :-)

Comment: @Aurèle Actually, I've just edited my answer. I've just made it simpler and something was weird. I was sure that your solution would be quadratic with `N` and that mine would be just linear, which wasn't the case. It now seems to be, so that it is always super fast :').